# How do you properly get/deploy ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment

I'm thoroughly confused about how to properly deploy ASP.NET MVC with my application. As far as I understand, there are the following ways you can get it on a machine:

- You can download a separate installer and install it on a machine that has the approprite .NET framework (although which MVC version requires which .NET framework?)
- Some versions come along with .NET framework itself (though I can't find which version of MVC is shipped with which version of .NET);
- Some versions are installed with Visual Studio (though again, no idea which versions are installed with which versions of VS). In this case, you can set `Copy Locally` to `true` for these references and perform a "bin deploy". You might need to add some extra references though (not sure which though).
- You can also download MVC as a NuGet package, in which case it also downloads some other unrelated packages like WebPages, Infrastructure and Razor (which is my personal WTF - wasn't Razor a core part of MVC?). In this case the build process will automatically do a "bin deploy" by default (I think...)

So... WTF? What is the proper way to add MVC to your development workstation, what is the proper way to add the references to your project (NuGet? GAC?), and what is the proper way to deploy it to the target server (separate installer? .NET installer? bin deploy?)

Answer (score 0):

**"Proper" Development:**

The "proper way" (by which I mean standard/redistributable way) would be using Nuget for your references. This means you can easily manage different versions and anybody else working on your project has a standard repository from which to pull the external requirements.

The [NuGet documentation](http://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started) has a decent explanation of how to add references.

To install the appropriate version of MVC for developing through Visual Studio, just download and install it from the [ASP.NET MVC website](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4). This will install the necessary templates for you to create a new MVC project in Visual Studio. This will also include the necessary binaries, etc.

**"Proper" Deployment:**

Use bin deploy to deploy to your webserver. This means you don't need full admin priviledges to install the MVC requirements.

[Phil Haack's guide](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx) will walk you through the process of bin deploying MVC3+

Keep in mind, the web server does need the appropriate .NET platform installed. You should install this via the [appropriate redistributable installer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30653) if it is not already installed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the deployment i publish my asp.net app (i usually make web applications) to the file system in a directory (you can set also a server there, but i don't like it) and make an upload to the server with an FTP client of all the deployed folders. All the changes that i make to the app after (like bug correction) i deploy all the app again and upload single parts.

I hope i get your question in part, this is my first answer in SO.

Comment: I see no mention of MVC in your answer, I'm not sure you've addressed the OP's question(s).

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this is quite unrelated.